# How to replace '-u username -p password' with new value in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

old value:  `10.125.11.5:27017 -u username -p password`
new value:  `10.125.19.6:27017`

I want to replace all the old value in *.py files (current directory folder and subdirectory) using shell,how to do?

seems sed or grep can not work with'-u' or '-p'.

Comment: ..you have your password just in the files ..??!

Comment: Is the old value a literal string or are `10.125.11.5:27017`, `username`, `password` are just placeholders that can differ from file to file?

Comment: You want to replace the ip only? or the ip and the username and password? The title says one thing but the body of your question says something different. The title suggests you want yo replace the string `-u username -p password` but in the body you rather delete that part and change the ip.

Comment: @Harim, it's false that "sed or grep can not work with -u or -p". As long as that value is contained inside a quoted string, and the `-` isn't the start of that string, they work perfectly well. And if you *do* want to search for a string that starts with a dash, that's what the `-e` argument to `grep` is for: `printf '%s\n' "line that does not match" "line containing -p" | grep -e -p`, if you want to test for yourself.

Comment: @Harim, ...and you don't need `-e` or anything like it if the dash isn't the beginning of the argument; for example, `grep ' -p'` works without the `-e` because it has a space between the opening quote and the dash.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We really need a *"Givez mez the codez"* Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an inputfile with this content:

```
$ cat inputfile
10.125.11.5:27017 -u username -p password
```

After executing this:

```
$ sed -e "s,10.125.11.5:27017 -u username -p password,10.125.19.6:27017,g" -i inputfile
```

You get this input file:

```
$ cat inputfile
10.125.19.6:27017
```

That should help with your issue.

Comment: That works, at least it solves your initial question. Maybe if you provide more details we can help you even more.

Comment: The "sed" command provided modifies the inputfile without the need to add redirections like '>'

Comment: @aicastell sorry, did not see the `-i` at the end. Maybe the problem is, that the files do not contain `-u password` but `-u supersecret123` and your command was just copy-pasted.

Comment: my file is:
10.125.11.5:27017 -u appuser -p appPass0rd[backup]


,I think the problem shoud be '[' or ']'

Comment: @Harim, right, in a regex, `[` and `]` begin and end a character class unless they're escaped. `\[` and `\]` do not have that behavior.

Comment: @Harim, ...btw, please add that actual content as an edit to the question (not an answer). See the "edit" link right at the bottom of the question itself.

Comment: I can't understand why somebody is downvotting my answer. Just trying to help somebody with a question. The answer is as good as posible, taking into account the provided information.

Comment: I agree the answer is as good as it can  be provided the question. I wouldn't dowbvote it, which I don't get is why is choosen as the right answer when from the comments it is clear this does not answer the (real, still not properly formulated) question.

Comment: @myradio I agree with you, this is not completely solved and also I don't understand why somebody accepted my answer as the valid. I hope who asks this question edits and adds the relevant information needed to try to fix it completely.

Comment: Well, only the OP can accept an answer, which makes everything more ambiguous.

Comment: He formulates the wrong question, he says this answer does not work, he admits the question was wrong,  still comes and accepts this answer without any edit nor comment...